# How could i send the setStateAction in useState React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
const [SBMenu,setSBMenu] = useState(<MainMenu Menu={setSBMenu}/>)
```

how could i send the setStateAction in useState .
I Know that we can't but is there any solution to send it because we can't access to the setStateAction before initialization

Comment: you can use function as the parameter of useState. you may use that form of useState...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why you want to set a rendered component as a state, it's not very common.

Suppose you want to do that, you can't have a cyclic logic

```
  const [a, b] = fn(c(b))
```

`b` is not defined yet. You most likely need to think of what's `b` first in your code.